# How to rectify the key error while converting CSV to json

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am converting csv to json

- I m merging the Email flag if country is same.

csv file is below

```
Country,Email,Flag
Germany,abc@network.com,Y
France,def@network.com,Y
Germany,ac@network.com,Y
```

COde is below

```
import csv
data= []
with open('a.csv') as obj:
    csv_content = obj.read().split('\n')
    csv_file = csv.reader(csv_content)
    csv_file_list = list(csv_file)
    csv_file_list_n = [x for x in csv_file_list if x != []]
    for entry in csv_file_list_n[1:]:
        row = {key: entry[idx] for idx, key in enumerate(csv_file_list_n[0])}
#         print(row)
        merge_flag = False
        for item in data:
            if item['Country'] == row['Country']:
                merge_flag = True
                item['Email'] = [item['Email'] , row['Email']]
                break
        if not merge_flag:
            data.append(row)
data
```

My output is below

```
[{'Country': 'Germany',
  'Email': ['abc@network.com', 'ac@network.com'],
  'Flag': 'Y'},
 {'Country': 'France', 'Email': 'def@network.com', 'Flag': 'Y'}]
```

- I want to handle if there are null keys

Below csv is example

```
Country,Email,Flag
Germany,abc@network.com,Y
England,
France,def@network.com,Y
Germany,ac@network.com,Y
Wales
```

You can see England is coming with comma and Whales is coming without comma

Expected out is below, default flag will be N

```
[{'Country': 'Germany',
  'Email': ['abc@network.com', 'ac@network.com'],
  'Flag': 'Y'},
 {'Country': 'France', 'Email': 'def@network.com', 'Flag': 'Y'},
{'Country': 'England', 'Flag': 'N'},
{'Country': 'Wales', 'Flag': 'N'}]
```

By using above code i am getting index error

Comment: As a side note, the country is called "Wales", not "Whales"...

Comment: You can check for key presence by using `if "Email" in item:`.

Comment: Or you can do `item.get('Email', <your default value here>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following approach. Use a `DictReader()` to read the CSV in as dictionary rows. This will automatically add `None` for missing keys. Use a  `defaultdict(list)` to group rows by country. Then build your required output format:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

countries = defaultdict(list)

with open('a.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
    
    for row in csv_input:
        countries[row['Country']].append([row['Email'], row['Flag'] if row['Flag'] else 'N'])

data = []

for country, entries in countries.items():
    row = {'Country' : country}
    
    for email, flag in entries:
        if email:
            if 'Email' in row:
                row['Email'].append(email)
            else:
                row['Email'] = [email]
        if flag:
            row['Flag'] = flag

    data.append(row)
    
print(data)
```

This would give you :

```
[
    {'Country': 'Germany', 'Email': ['abc@network.com', 'ac@network.com'], 'Flag': 'Y'}, 
    {'Country': 'England', 'Flag': 'N'}, 
    {'Country': 'France', 'Email': ['def@network.com'], 'Flag': 'Y'}, 
    {'Country': 'Wales', 'Flag': 'N'}
]
```